# regex to replace a word if it doesn't have specific one before

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Using regex in C# I should replace one word if it doesn't have specific one before
In my example it to replace "Ballmer" with "Steve Ballmer"

In:

```
...text...Ballmer...text
```

Result:

```
...text...Steve Ballmer...text
```

but if "Steve" already there, I shouldn't add Steve again.

In:

```
...text...Steve Ballmer...text
```

Result:

```
...text...Steve Ballmer...text
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` and positive lookahead `(?=...)`

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!Steve )(?=Ballmer)", "Steve ");
```

Comment: Say, is it just a matter of taste to use the zero-width match or does it actually have any benefits (performance or otherwise), since this seems to be quite often the difference between our solutions :D.

Comment: @m.buettner - I see nothing positive on solutions that remove and then insert word that is already in, as you do with `Ballmer` word. Besides of that, you didn't provide a replacement code in your original answer, as you have added it later based on my answer :)

Comment: @m.buettner Performance-wise, the difference is probably negligible. But at least you save yourself from repeating a word or phrase (in this case "Ballmer"). And Ωmega, what's wrong with improving one's answer? :-) Answers are editable for a reason, as improvement (even by strangers) is encouraged.

Comment: @Wiseguy - Nothing wrong at all, I just pointed on differences and I ended my comment with :)

Comment: @Ωmega, yes I didn't want to dispute the legitimation of your answer, since it definitely improved on my answer. I was just wondering whether there are any other reasons than removal of unnecessary duplication. I just usually don't include things like this in my answers because it makes them harder to understand for OPs who are still getting to grips with regex basics (same as the arguably micro optimization of putting `?:` in every nevessary subgroup, that doesn't need to be captured)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) when matching `Ballmer`:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!Steve )Ballmer", "Steve Ballmer");
```

This will do exactly what you want. Match any `Ballmer` that is not immediately preceded by `Steve` (and a space).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are fun, but it's also worthwhile to try simpler tools before resorting to the big guns. This particular problem can be solved with basic find-and-replace

1. Replace "Ballmer" with "Steve Ballmer"
2. Replace "Steve Steve Ballmer" with "Steve Ballmer" (to correct for any oversteving)

---

Alternatively

1. Replace "Steve Ballmer" with "Ballmer"
2. Replace "Ballmer" with "Steve Ballmer"